# Reference a hidden defined form field in PHP

Tags: php, sql, dreamweaver

I am trying to create a template commenting system using Dreamweaver for a site. I have the form setup to submit the webpage and corresponding text to a mysql db. the webpage value is a hidden form field.

The form submits to the db okay but I want to create a repeating view for the comments. How do I reference the hidden form field so I can use it where "WHERE webpage=""" is called?

UPDATE: By repeating view I mean:

```
 <?php do { ?>
     <p><?php echo $row_InsertRecords['text']; ?></p>
     <?php } while ($row_InsertRecords = mysql_fetch_assoc($InsertRecords));     ?>
```

My problem is I need to make partial edits to the PHP for that template so I can retrieve comments specific to the child page but Dreamweaver won't let me. It either propogates ALL of the PHP or none of it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'a repeating view for the comments'? Can you show us any code to start with?

Comment: I just did an internet search on your question: returned was this: [A repeating region is a section of a template that can be duplicated many times in a template-based page.](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/creating-repeating-regions-templates.html). I had a quick look - it may be useful. If you want more detailed PHP code then more details are required.

Comment: the repeating region section of my template code and child pages is fine. My problem comes when the recordset to repeat is defined before that outisde the html in php. I use the sql "SELECT text FROM commentDB" in the template file and thought I could add "WHERE webpage="[fill filname here]" on the different childpages. I cannot do this in Dreamweaver. So I was wondering if I could define a hidden value in the comment form below that php and reference the variable's value when making the sql query? Or if there is any other way to create a html var and refer to it via php?

Comment: Woohoo! Found this solution where I can use php to generate the filename and store/retrieve it from the db to identify the correct comments needed. Using basename....I'm still a PHP newbie but I'm learning bit by bit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dynamic commenting system that uses the templates in Dreamweaver, you can use the following code in your dwt file:

```
$fname=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$query_ViewRecords = "SELECT * FROM commentsDB WHERE id='".$fname."'";
```

id can match a hidden value in your comment form defined as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="IDField" value=<?php echo "\"$fname\""; ?>/>
```

The code above was part of code generated by Dreamweaver's DB functions that were later edited by me to add the WHERE clause. This way you can generate HTML that matched each child page when it is created by the template. Make sure codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked parameter is set to true for these changes to propagate to the child pages.